# timing with attr in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

how to set timing with attr in jquery
for example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".searchicon").click(function(){
    $(".searchbox").show(400);
  })
```

it will take 400 ms to show

i have this

```
  $(".menu_icon").click(function(){
    $(".drop_menu").attr("class","menu_responsive");
  });
```

how to add also timing to this function
i review documentation 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/
but no way for this

Comment: What is expected result if element already has `"menu_responsive"` `className` set?

Comment: There is no timing when changing an attribute, it happens right away. If you want to just delay the setting of the attribute, use a `setTimeout`

Comment: thanks setTimeout working fine , i also find another way with animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help
there is two ways to timing attr
1 - setTimeout

```
setTimeout('$(".drop_menu").attr("class","menu_responsive");',1000);
```

but this will shown immediately after set time
2 - animate()

```
$(".drop_menu").attr("class","menu_responsive").animate({width:"300px"}, 1000);
```

i used animate and set time of animation and works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the element, as in your first example, just chain the show() method:

```
$(".menu_icon").click(function(){
  $(".drop_menu").attr("class","menu_responsive").show(400);
});
```